# Panorama inner elements animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation

When my user swipes to the next panorama item, the elements inside the new panorama item must animate their entrance with different delays.

```
←TextBlock
  ←TextBlock
    ←TextBlock
```

First textblock animates with panorama item. Second animates the same way, but with some delay before it etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="Line One" toolkit:SlideInEffect.LineIndex="1"/>
<TextBlock Text="Line Two" toolkit:SlideInEffect.LineIndex="2"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I installed Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit and added a reference for it, but when i'm typing 'toolkit:' where is no option for 'SlideInEffect'...

Comment: You must have installed the wrong version of the toolkit, you gotta download the last one using NuGet or go straight to codeplex (http://phone.codeplex.com) and get it. The SlideInEffect is available since the october 2012 update.

Comment: Yes, i've download wptoolkit with NuGet (11.06.2013). There are 3 toolkit dll files in directories: wp8, sl4-windowsphone71 and sl3-wp. Only last one works for me. May be i'ts not available for windows phone 7.1? Sorry for stupid questions, i'm newby in Visual Studio

Comment: it works both for WP7.1 and WP8, use the sl-wp71 but before you gotta check if your installed SDK is the latest one, you must be using an old version of the SDK.